# Update Timestamp in Firestore with React

Tags: reactjs, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a date field ( timestamp ) in fireStore, by sending a timestamp.
But Firestore receive it as a number, then not as timestamp.

I saw many topics about serverTimestamp but it just explain how to store the "now" timestamp, and I need to store a past timestamp.

Is there some specificly function to convert the timestamp to an object that firestore can reconize as a timestamp ?

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the code that's not working the way you expect, it's very difficult to figure out what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing a date in Firestore should be as simple as setting a field to the `Date` object with the value that you want to be stored. E.g.

```
doc.publishDate = new Date('December 17, 2018 03:24:00');
```

If you're having trouble with that, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok it was almost that yes, I wanted to do it with a timestamp and it works. Thanks